What is this washer called and how do I find a replacement?
I recently acquired a 2018 Honda NC750S. One of the previous owners mouted an aftermarket center stand, where one of the two mounting screws (including washers) went missing. I found the manual of the stand, and I am currently looking for replacement parts, but there is one part of which I do not know the name nor do I know where to look for a replacement. It looks like two wide washers fused together. The part is identified by the letter "E" in the screenshot below:

(https://www.motea.com/media/montageanleitungen/constands/hauptstaender/981987.pdf)
In the same document, this part is later referred to as "25/14.5/10.5".


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Where are you located?

@devopsix Germany

If manufacturer and vendor can't help you, you might have luck finding a "Bundbuchse" of the right size.

The part you are looking at is actually a bushing. It is designed to keep the two metal parts apart so wear does not ensue and so it doesn't rattle. What it is made out of or where to get it is anyone's business.
As for where to find the part, I think you have one of two options. First, go back to whomever built the stand in the first place (I take it Honda didn't) and see if you can get a replacement. The second option may be to 3d print your own part. It appears there are dimensions you can work from to get something which will work. Something like this is a "one off" built for the exact dimensions and fit. Chances are you won't be able to get something off the shelf.

By "3D printing", do you mean household plastic or resin printers or do you refer to professional metal printing?

@curious - As in plastic/resin. You could have it printed in nylon and it would stand up quite well to what it'll be doing.

@curious - Contact Motea and see if you can get parts for the stand. You have all the information you need from the PDF: https://motea.com - PN: 981987 ... you can also contact ConStands: https://www.constands.com/en/

Your suggestion about contacting the retailer was spot-on, it looks like they might have replacements in stock. I'll report back and accept your answer if that solves the issue.

@curious - Thumbs up! :o)

Took a bit of back-and-forth between me and the retailer since you cannot order replacement parts via the website, but today I received a small bag that contains all the mounting hardware, including replacement springs. Had to pay EUR 25 including shipping. Still have to test if everything fits, but my question is answered. Thanks a lot!
